# How to adjust for age effect in an ANOVA?

Tags: r, regression, anova

I recently submitted a paper to a peer-review journal. The aim is to assess whether census blocks with worst material deprivation index in a given region are those that have the lowest levels of access to health emergency services (in terms of travel time taking into account the location of services and location of ambulances - accumulated time).

For this we did the following: after measuring the MDI (material deprivation index - a rather classical index) and obtaining the total journey times to the emergency services, we performed an ANOVA (MDI as a categorical variable - 6 levels - and times as a continuous variable). I did it using R.

The reviewer now says that we should see if there is an effect of age. He argues that in some countries, the more deprived patients are also the youngest. He adds that the effect of age could be taking into account in a linear regression (or ordered logistic regression if normality was not assumed) with the proportion of aged 30 (for example) as an independent variable in addition to MDI categories. Thus, we will obtain the beta coefficient of the effect of MDI on travel times adjusted on age (mean age).

To get a view of the age effect, I intuitively would have added an age structure indicator (for example the % of young people, % of older people, etc.) and ANOVA would become an ANCOVA. It would simply be an ANOVA with an additional covariate. But the reviewer suggests a linear or logistic regression. Does it make sense to you? As a non-statistician, I am not sure about what I should do in this case.

Hope I am not too confuse. Please tell me if I am, I will try to clarify.
Thanks in advance,
Cheers

PS: I am not a native English speaker and my English is rather poor. Apologies for the mistakes.

Comment: You should provide an example.

Comment: I think your English is good and I think you want to use a linear model. Doing the model inference is a specialized skill, do you have a statistics group at your institute that you could ask?

Comment: Cross-validated may be a better place for your queries.

Comment: Hi miguel, welcome to Stack Overflow. This website focuses on *specific* **programing** questions. It seems your question centers more on selection and interpretation of statistical analysis. Therefore, your question is likely more appropriate for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com). I have voted to migrate it there.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I will post my question in CrossValidated!